# Why can't I set attribute "TYPE" of LI element in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've just come to an unusual beghavior of Internet Explorer IE (v8.0.6001.18904).
When I try to set "type" attribute of any <LI> element, it will result into error.
I used jQuery (v1.32):

```
$('<li>').attr("type", "test");

or

$('<li type="test">');
```

The same thing works for DIV. LI element does not seem to have "type" attribute reserved by HTML or XHTML definitions. It also might be jQuery issue.

Solution is simple - just use another attribute name :-)

But is there someone out there who knows WHY does this error occur? Could it happen with another attribute names? Why the error comes with LI element only?

UPDATE: Quick solution for this issue:

```
$('<li>').data("type", "test");
```

Comment: Are you using strict doc type?

Comment: Why are you trying to use the `type` attribute? It's use is only for setting the `list-style-type`, which should really be set in CSS. `type` isn't valid on `div`, and since you are happy to use any old attribute I think you should explain why you are trying to do this so we can provide more appropriate answers.

Comment: I'm using STRICT doc type, which could be the reason.
I use attribute "type" to store some string information for my needs (well now I use another attribute name :)

Comment: That isn't how you should be using HTML attributes. For one thing, what if your custom attribute is repurposed by the browser for something else? Your use of that attribute would be invalid. If you want to add custom data you can use jQuery's data mechanism (Like Nick Craver said) or, if you switch to using HTML5, use custom `data-*` attributes. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-data for more information.

Comment: akamike - The data method of jQuery is ideal for this stuff. On the other hand I thought I AM ALLOWED to use my custom attributes in (X)HTML 4+ unless it collides with (X)HTML DTD attributes... or is it against W3 standard to use my own attributes?

Comment: It's appropriate if you use a custom DTD :)

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_type.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using attributes for this, jQuery provides another mechanism with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), a quick example:

```
$("li").data("type", "test");

$("li").click(function() {
  alert($(this).data("type")); //alerts "test"
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this perfectly solves the issue. (for jQuery) (nice for production and slightly worse for debugging - you can't see the value by quickly looking into DOM explorer :-)

Comment: @Petr - Just a tip, if you're using a console of any type, you can do `$(this).data()` to dump the entire collection on that element :)